# Does a single token protect against csrf in a RESTful API?

Tags: rest, api, http, csrf, access-token

Consider I'm creating a RESTful API (like Twitter API) and I need only a single key token to access the endpoint `GET /messages`.

- The token needs to be sent via header `access_token` for example.
- If I don't pass the token I'll get an 4xx error.

In the RESTful API scenario, is this all needed to protect against CSRF attacks? I mean, in RESTful APIs I'm not using Cookies to manager a user session, since the idea here is to not be a session (Stateless is one of the principles of REST).

Am I forgetting something or is this correct? I don't see why I would need a `anti CSRF token` besides my access token.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: if your access_token is not a cookie, yes, it's enough to protect you against CSRF.

Long answer:

A CSRF attack can only happen when HTTP client **automatically** sends some authentication data(usually cookies) to server. The key point is attacker do not need to know the Cookie, it's is automatically sent if web user accesses 2 sites(your site and the attacker's site) using the same browser.

To anti CSRF, server sends to client a private token that browser does not automatically send it to server(so it's must not be a cookie). The developer has to write code to attach the token to each subsequent request.

CSRF is an issue for using Cookie by Web browser, if you are developing restful API that is not used by web browser, usually, you do not need to care about CSRF

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have one last comment: The only problem I see using access_token in my header is if my RESTful API sends the Access Controll Allow Origin with "*" value. In this case, the cross site request would be possible if the attacker knows my token (sniffing or something). the attacker would not get the token from localStorage in the browser because the browser does not allow this for security reasons. Is that right? Is this a possible "weakness" if my API works like that?

Comment: CSRF attack is for the case the attacker does not know your secret data. So, there is no flaw for CSRF in your implementation. If the attacker "knows my token (sniffing or something)", it's another kind of attack, you can  make another question with more detail information. For example about sniffing attack, You can defend it simply by using HTTPS

Answer (score 0):

@Bart Firstly CSRF attacks are usually from a trusted user. Which means that the client has successfully authenticated himself by maybe passing a valid token in case of a rest API. The attack could be by passing let's say a javascript which can change the state of a resource. So just having a single key token won't really help to avoid CSRF attacks.

Please refer to below URL for more reference on CSRF :-

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

Most of the frameworks like Spring have inbuilt support for CSRF.

Comment: "Which means that the client has successfully authenticated himself by maybe passing a valid token in case of a rest API. The attack could be by passing let's say a javascript which can change the state of a resource." If I need always the token in all requests of my RESTful API I would not need nothing anymore, right? In your example you assumed you logged in a RESTful API and the next requests would not contain the token, but RESTful APIs does not save states (sessions) because it necessary uses tokens. =/